# Why do most logos 'move' from left to right?

Tags: logo

I was browsing logo examples, which represent some not symmetric object (usually in movement, like - trains, cars, plains, etc).

And realized, that logos, where 'movement' is from left to right look more attractive to me (not considering other characteristics), than right to left.

Have you noticed it?

I have a suggestion, that effect of such kind of logos depends on each person brain leading hemisphere.

So my leading hand is right. That would mean that making this kind of logos move from left to right will make it attractive to absolute majority of people (70+%), and is better just from statistical point of view.

Do you know some researched-based information on these specific topic?

Comment: One suggestion would be that it corresponds with the direction one reads their language in.

Answer (score 7):

As DA01 suggested, this is related to reading direction. Because we, in the West, read from left to right, this direction corresponds in our minds to 'forward' and 'the future'. Right-to-left is 'backwards' and 'in the past'. This technique is also applied in photography and comic writing: models/characters facing right are going forward, either in direction or in plot. Characters facing left are reminiscing, being unproductive to the plot or are facing an obstacle.

You can use diagonals to appeal to this effect even stronger: a diagonal from bottom left to upper right is suggesting an upward graph or motion and is thus perceived as more positive that one from top left to bottom right.

In cultures with a right-to-left reading pattern (eg. Arabic, Hebrew), the effect is reversed. Left-to-right is backwards and 'past', right-to-left is forward and constructive.

Comment: The reasons you're giving for this seem rather hand-wavy—for example, reading direction is also top to bottom, yet up is forward.

Comment: Good point. I can't back my claims with evidence, I'm just repeating what I hear designers, photographers and comic book artists say. I've heard it said often, so it must hold some water, right? :)

Comment: These things are most certainly culturally related. One further point: designers tend to prefer motion "into the composition" rather than out of it (without some reason to move the other way).

Answer (score 6):

To add to this discussion, I'm sure most graphic designers are aware of the implicit forward arrow created in the negative space in FedEx's logo.

[image]

What you might not have seen is the Arabic FedEx logo that actually has the arrow pointing to the left!

[image]

I think it's a real word example of different cultural mentalities of motion and more specifically, as in this case, progress. I really feel that the "attractiveness" of logos as you put it, is often dictated by cultural norms of reading direction and this is a functional real world example.

Comment: And on their trucks the arrow points forward and backwards on opposite sides.

Answer (score 0):

I see it's been 7 years since this was posted, but I came here because I noticed the other day that most car logos with animals on them move from right to left. I guess my curiosity is just wondering why that is. I know about left to right meaning progress and moving froward from film theory, so why do so many cars go right to left?
If the image shows up notice 11 out of 15 car logos with animals move right to left. Including the biggest names in the industry, porsche, mustang, jaguar

[image]

Comment: Hello Adrian, welcome to GDSE. We try to adhere to a pretty strict Q&A format here. That means Answer fields are reserved for, well, answers. If you have a new or follow-up question, please ask it via the [Ask Question](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button at the top of the page. You can also take the [tour] to get to know our workings a little better. Feel free to browse the site, ask questions and maybe leave an answer.